# Removing the class name in javascript from array

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning javascript. So,to remove class from an element 
we use `element.classList.remove("mystyle");` But to remove from an array, my tutor is using another way,which I havent seen and its confusing me:

```js
        var el = document.querySelectorAll('.myClass');
        for (var x = 0; x < el.length; x++) {
            el[x].onclick = function () {
                upClass(el, 'active', 'remove');
                if (!this.classList.contains('active')) {
                    this.classList.add('active');
                }
                
            }
        }

        function upClass(e, c, a) {
          for (var x = 0; x < e.length; x++) {
                e[x].classList[a](c);    
            }
        }
```

```css
   .box1 {
            background-color: aqua;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            color: #fff;
        }
        
        .box2 {
            background-color: red;
            font-size: 0.5em;
            color: #ddd;
        }
        
        #one,
        #two,
        #three {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        
        .active {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Complete JavaScript Course</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    <div id="one" class="myClass">Box One</div>
    <div id="two" class="myClass active">Box Two</div>
    <div id="three" class="myClass">Box Three</div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Here,in this function given below:

```
 function upClass(e, c, a) {
          for (var x = 0; x < e.length; x++) {
                e[x].classList[a](c);    
            }
        }
```

`e` is passed as list of element to remove **active** class.When,this function upClass() gets called up in console i did `el`:

```
NodeList(3) [div#one.myClass, div#two.myClass.active, div#three.myClass]
0: div#one.myClass
1: div#two.myClass.active
2: div#three.myClass
length: 3
__proto__: NodeList
```

So,I tried to remove the active class in console using:

```
el[1].classList.remove('active');
```

But,my tutor is using  `e[x].classList[a](c);` where i got stuck to understand `classList[a](c).`.If i see the values passed from above it becomes with each iteration:

```
for x=0,1,2
el[x].classList['remove']('active');
```

Can someone provide me any other example to understand how is this  `e[x].classList[a](c);` working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript there are two ways to access a property named `foo` of an object `bar`: either `bar.foo` or `bar['foo']`. These do exactly the same. And functions are just properties too! So `bar.foo()` can also be written as `bar['foo']()`. The advantage of the latter is that `'foo'` is no longer an identifier in your program; it can actually be a value that comes from a variable.

So by writing `upClass` in this way, you can pass either `add` or `remove` for the argument `a`, so the function can be used for both operations.

For example, if we call

```
upClass(document.getElementsByClassName('myClass'), 'active', 'remove')
```

then `classList[a]` is the same as `classList['remove']`, which is the same as `classList.remove`, so `classList[a](c)` will simply call `classList.remove('active')`.

In my opinion, this function is way too "clever", especially if it's meant for teaching. It reminds me of this famous Kernighan quote:

> Debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?

Also, single letter function argument names? Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

classList is an object, and so contains key/value pairs, and to access a value in javascript, you can either do `classList.key` or `classList["key"]`. They will get the same thing.

`classList.remove` and `classList["remove"]` are the same function, so you can call `classList["remove"]("active")` exactly as you would call `classList.remove("active")`.